# Delphi sql: dealing with space character in field name

Tags: sql, delphi, paradox

Ho do I deal in the sql text with fields that have a space character.
For example in db biolife I have the field: Species Name
both my attempts did not work:

```
query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Species Name FROM biolife';
query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT ''Species Name'' FROM biolife';
```

The first one gives error, the second gives wrong result.

Comment: `query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT [Species Name] FROM biolife';` in case of MS SQL; `query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT "Species Name" FROM biolife';` in case of Oracle

Comment: I just tried that and it does not work with paradox

Comment: Try double quotes (not two single quotes).  That works in most databases.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. With double quotes also: SELECT "Species Name"
But it returns the name of the fields instead of the value

Comment: There must be a way to do that in paradox tables

Comment: Thanks GuidoG. Yes this is duplicate. There I found my answer:
SELECT biolife."Species Name"

Comment: So if it works there why does it not works for you. What error do you get ?

Comment: Adding biolife. (the name of the table) before the fieldname enclosed in double quotes solved the problem